How many ways can 4n participants be paired into teams of two, with each pair competing against another pair?
This was a question in my combinatorics class. I missed the lecture and am trying to get the answer myself.

Consider a group of $4n$ participants. The participants are paired
into groups of two, such that each pair (team) of two participants is
matched with another group (team) as their opponents.
How many distinct pairings and matchings are possible?

I got $\frac{(4n)!}{(2!)^{2n} \cdot n!}$ for how to group the $4n$ participants into groups of $2$ and then $\frac{(2n)!}{(2!)^{n} \cdot n!}$ for how to pair up the groups of two. Multiplying the two together, I get $\frac{(4n)! \cdot (2n)!}{2^{3n} \cdot (n!)^2}$.
Now for the next part of the question.

In addition to determining the number of ways to pair and match participants, I also want to account for the seating arrangement of the participants around a circular table.
Each pair of teammates must sit opposite each other, and the two opposing teams must also sit opposite each other. Rotating the entire arrangement doesn’t count as a different configuration.
How many distinct circular seating arrangements are possible for each match?

I do not understand this part of the question, wouldn't the answer be the same since it the previous solution accounted for these duplicates?

I do not understand why you do not understand. So what if the answer is the same? (Not saying that it is) If that's the case, maybe they want you to lead you on to finding a bijection? $\quad$ FWIW I don't think it's the same, so I'd encourage you to edit with details of how you would approach the problem to get the same answer.

I do not see how adding in a circular table changes this problem at all. I am not sure what they are looking for in a solution. Could you also elaborate on why you think they are not the same?

Re circular table, if there were no restrictions, do you know how sitting these 4n people in a line, differs from sitting them in a circular table where rotations are the same? $\quad$ I realize that I took " and the two opposing teams must also sit opposite each other." to simply mean that all teams sit opposite each other, but then that won't explain why they had such a phrasing. Maybe they want the 4 people in a match to sit at right angles to each other?

If you use n=1 as a test case, you'll notice that your answer to the first question is wrong. Check the denominator again. It's almost right.

In your first step, when choosing the number of teams, you should divide by $(2n)!$ not $n!$ as there are $2n$ teams.

An apt question with the US Open nearing its climax!
Tthe first part of your answer is incorrect.
We can simultaneously hold all the doubles matches on n numbered courts in $\dfrac{(4n)!}{(4!)^n}$ ways
But we are only interested in the number of groups of $4$, not who goes to which court, so we can form $\dfrac{(4n)!}{n!(4!)^n }$ groups of $4$
After this is where your attempt goes askew. Suppose you are among one of the groups of $4$, you can form only three distinct doubles teams
Thus finally, number of distinct doubles matches =$ \dfrac{(4n)!\cdot3^n}{n!(4!)^n}$

Regarding the second part, there are two ambiguities. Firstly, are the seats numbered or not ? And while this can be overcome by specifying one or the other I simply can't understand how I can sit opposite my partner and at the same time the two opposing teams also sit opposite each other!

Is $4^n$ supposed to be $(4!)^n$? If not could you explain why?

@Nic: Ty, typos corrected !
